# Changing fonts of text and styles of Input boxes in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How can I change the font of the columns ie have a different font for each of the 4 (TYPE, DIRECTION, DATE and OPTION)?
How can i change the style/colour of the 4 input boxes, for example the first 2 are of one style and the second 2 of another?

Current code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime
from datetime import date

columns = ["TYPE","DIRECTION","DATE","OPTION"]
param = (20,3) # size of the main window

def GUI():
    sg.theme('Dark Brown 1')
    listing = [sg.Text(u, size = param) for u in columns]
    core = [
    sg.Input(size = param),
    sg.Input(size = param),
    sg.Input(size = param),
    sg.Input(size = param)]
   
    mesh = [[x,y] for (x,y) in list(zip(listing, core))]
    layout =[[sg.Button("SEND")]]+ mesh
    window = sg.Window('Trade Entry System', layout, font='Courier 12').Finalize()
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "SEND":
            break
        else:
            print("OVER")
        break
    window.close()
GUI()
``
```

Comment: Just using different values for options `font`, `background_color` and `text_color` of element.